# TempData always return null from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-core, tempdata

In my ASP.NET Core action method, at the end of the action, I am storing a value into `TempData` like this:

```
  TempData["FileURL"] = model.ToFileConvertedURL;
```

Here is my view

```
<form asp-controller="PdfToWordController" asp-action="Download">
    @if (TempData["FileURL"] != null)
    {
        <input asp-action="Download" type="submit" value="Download" class="btn btn-primary" />
    }
</form>
```

When I click the download button it should hit following action in controller.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("pdf-to-word-converter/download")] 
public async Task<IActionResult> Download()
{
    string URL = string.Empty;

    if (TempData.ContainsKey("FileURL"))
        URL = TempData["FileURL"].ToString(); 

    byte[] fileBytes = null;

    // Download Word file
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(URL))
    {
        fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(URL);
    }

    return File(fileBytes, "application/force-download", "ddd");
}
```

But `TempData` always is null. I want to same action fire when user click download button again and again. What is the issue here? Is `TempData` is the right thing to use?

Comment: it's probably not a great idea to use this... sounds like it'd be similar to using a server-side session var.  Is there a reason you don't persist this using models/parameters?  Remember that the .cshtml file is only going to know the bound view model parameters anyway, so if you do still use TempData, you need to pass it along to the model...

Comment: Looks like your requirement is a "server push data to client" model, let's assume a scenario, one user is uploading his file which wants to share with other users, whenever the file is uploaded(it may take several seconds), a download button should appear in other users website... Just like a chat app and using Signalr seems to be a solution. And about the `TempData`, I found the [document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0#tempdata) and hope it could help.

Comment: if your scenario is like, some user upload a file and then your code do the convert, and after that when the user visit the target page again and want to check if the file can be downloaded, then I think you should store the `is converted` state into some place such as database, and each time render the page, going to that place to query if the file is converted and return the result back to the  view.